# i am trying to convert binary file to ascii and the to XML using java i need a package for ASN.1 grammar

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, bouncycastle, asn.1

To convert binary successfully to ASCII and the XML i need java package that has ASN.1 grammar I'm currently using bouncycastle for converting ASN.1 to ASCII

Comment: *To convert ASN.1 successfully to ASCII and the XML*. That doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you can supply an example to clarify.

Comment: What does *convert ASN.1 to ASCII* mean? ASN.1 is already ASCII.

Comment: in telecom they use mediation systems to convert up stream network components to down stream business part  so mediation convert these binary data probably in asn.1 to a readable format for downstream system part csv , xml , json we are trying to do the same we can use XER encoding rules but we need ASN.1 grammar first https://www.itu.int/en/ITU-T/asn1/Pages/XML-encoding-rules-(XER)-for-ASN-1.aspx

Comment: It's not clear what your question is.  If you're looking for an ASN.1 grammar for your message data, you'll have to go locate the specification for the messages you're working with and find where they have specified the ASN.1 grammar.  3GPP, for example, has many specification documents that contain ASN.1 grammars.

Comment: What's the question?